# Architecture for maintaining groups of people?

Tags: rest

My situation is as follows:

```
Person belongsTo Group
Group hasMany People

When creating a new Person, a Group needs to be specified.
```

I am trying to decide on URLs that best follow REST.  Right now my URLs are sort of confusing, which leads me to believe they aren't RESTful.

I have functionality that allows a User to:

1. Get a single Person, all People in a Group, or all People
2. Add a new Person to a Group (a group needs to be specified)
3. Edit a Person's information
4. Delete a Person

My URLs are:

### GET

```
/people/group/id -> Gets all People in a Group
/people/person/id -> Gets a single Person
/people/all -> Gets all People
```

### PUT

```
/people/group/id -> Add a new Person to a Group
```

### POST

```
/people/person/id -> Edit a Person
```

### DELETE

```
/people/person/id -> Delete a Person
```

What can I do to make my URLs more RESTful?  Does anyone have any suggestions?

The reason I ask this is because I think of other structures and see how everything is simply determined by the HTTP request.  For example:

```
/people/id

GET retrieves the person, POST updates the person, DELETE removes the person.
```

In the case of no "Groups", it is so simple.  But in my "Groups" case, I need to specify parameters such as **all** in `/people/all` to GET all People or **/group/id** in `/people/groups/id` to specify where to POST a new Person.  Can I add parameters like that and still keep it RESTful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that there is any "right" way to do RESTful routes, it's all really up to you since there are no hard and fast rules, but here's how I would structure it. For people:

```
GET    /people     -> Returns a list of all people
POST   /people     -> Adds a new person (group would be defined in the POSTed data
PUT    /people/:id -> Updates a person
DELETE /people/:id -> Deletes a person
```

And then for groups with people as a RESTful endpoint:

```
GET    /groups/:id/members -> Gives a list of all people in the group
```

I chose members as the endpoint since it flows as plain english (get group members), but you could use people, or any other descriptive term.

When thinking about how you structure your RESTful routes I think the most important thing is to make them easily understandable for your eventual API users whether that will just be you, or third parties.

Comment: +1 because I definitely think its better to have /people and /groups/{id}/people rather than pushing groups underneath people - I would, however, have /people/{id}/groups to show which groups a person is a member of.  You could also have /people?group={groupid} as an alternate way of getting to a list of people in a specific group - I'm not sure either is more right than the other.  To me, it would depend on if you are providing methods to manipulate a group as a resource or not.